# Not able to run JMeter 5.0 through java exec command in console mode

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am not able to run JMeter through Java exec command in console mode whereas it is working fine on `Version 3.1`.

Refer below command i am using.

```
Process pro = null;  
pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jmeter.bat -n -t test.jmx");
```

Comment: show error in log

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't have enough information therefore we will not be able to answer.

Blind shot: your [Java Runtime version](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) is too low to run JMeter 5.0. Starting from [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32) it is required to have [Java 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/java8-2100321.html) or higher in order to be able to run JMeter so if you're sitting on previous Java version - you will have to upgrade your Java installation.

You can check your current Java version by running [`java -version` command in terminal](https://java.com/en/download/help/version_manual.xml)